# What is the safest and most effective approach when you need to pass data to another component through navigation in Angular8?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router

I´m currently developing an application based on user authentication where each user can register a student-campus as a teacher and currently, I'm on a feature where I have two routes:

**Route 1:** It has a Datagrid where I'm listing all of the student campuses that I've already created and each row has an edit button that navigates to "Route 2" and the purpose of that is to edit the already created student campus.

**Route 2:** It has a form with all the necessary fields to create a student-campus.

As you can see I need to pass the student-campus ID to fetch data in the ngOnInit to fill the fields and be able to edit the above-mentioned, so I have several options in consideration:

**Option 1:** Pass ID in the URL.

```
    this.router.navigate(['planteles/registrar', idPlantel]);
```

https://myapplication/planteles/registrar/1

**Option 2:** Pass ID in the URL with queryParams.

```
    this.router.navigate(['planteles/registrar'], { queryParams: { ID: idPlantel } });
```

https://myapplication/planteles/registrar?ID=1

**Option 3:** Pass ID in the state object of navigation extras.

```
    this.router.navigate(['planteles/registrar'], { state: { id: idPlantel } });
```

**Option 4:** Shared service and BehaviorSubject to subscribe to data.

```
    I owe you the code
```

I'm able to use any of these but I have a problem with each one of them.

I can't use Option 1 and Option 2 because the ID cannot be changed by the teacher because that gives him the possibility to fetch the student-campus data of another teacher and edit it, so it isn't safe.
The problem with option 3 and option 4 is when I refresh the page the state is lost.

Currently, I have a workaround with option 3 which is to redirect the user to the previous page if the state is undefined but I don't like that solution. I'd like to persist data if the user reloads the page without using LocalStorage.

Thanks in advance, all help or contribution is well appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 is the correct option here (and the way you will find most sites in the real world are implemented... including this one we're on now). The problem is your approach to web security, and what you need to fix is your backend. You're approaching web security as though front end security is real, it's not.  Web security exists on your backend.  Users should not be able to fetch or view or manipulate data that does not belong to them, and this must be enforced by your backend.

A high level example of how this might work: some secure authentication token should be granted when the user logs in, then this authentication token should be attached to each request.  The API then uses this token to check which user is making the request and ensures they have the proper permissions. If they do not (as in the case of the user editing their URL param to some ID they do not have permissions for) or if there is no token, the API should return a 401 or 403 response and the front end should handle it appropriately (ie sending them back to list, or showing an error page, whatever you decide)... how to issue this token, make it secure, and make use of it is an entirely separate topic beyond the scope of this answer.

In any of the options, I could open my dev tools, and view any API requests being made, and change the ID's and use that to view or manipulate other people's data without any effort at all.  So options 3 / 4 are barely more "safe" than 1 or 2. As none of these are safe without properly implemented backend security.

Front end "security" exists only as user experience. Me and you are both using the same URL to view this page, but we see different options and buttons, like you can edit or delete your post and accept answers, while I can't, but I can edit or delete my answer etc.  This isn't for true security purposes, SO's servers enforce who can and can't take what actions. It's just showing me and you the UI that reflects our different permissions, ie, its all just UX.

Comment: I completely agree. Currently, I'm using interceptors to attach the authentication token on every request and based In the example exposed above you'll only get the data if you pass the student-campus Id, the person's id and the bearer token to the API request, but I don't really know what behavior should I expect when the user change the ID from the URL, fill the form with new data and click the save button; should I save another record or should I show an error message to the user?

Comment: I'd just kick them back to the list or login if I get a 401/3 response as they're attempting to access data that doesn't belong to them.. this is also a use case for interceptors but on the response side.

Answer (score 1):

There's another way too, which is defined in Angular docs itself.

> **NavigationExtras**

Example:

```
 let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
        queryParams: {
            "firstname": "Nic",
            "lastname": "Raboy"
        }
    };
 this.router.navigate(["page2"], navigationExtras);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think this is option 2, isn't it?